# Time it takes soupy soil to firm up

Tags: drainage

Just had a curtain drain to address yet another spring in our back yard that was causing dampness in the crawlspace. If I could bottle this stuff I might become rich!

After the curtain drain was installed I noticed the areas on both sides were pretty soupy and would sink you pretty fast. The company used a backhoe and there was indeed a huge amount of water everywhere. He said it will firm up after the water has drained out. Does anyone have an idea of how long this might take? He said i can take 1-3 weeks and with rain in the next 2 days I suspect longer.

Thank you

Comment: Based on what you've said there is no real way to know.  It depends on how much water is there, how quickly more water is coming in, how quickly excess water is draining, the characteristics of the soil, and probably several other things.

Comment: It is sitting next to the new drain system so hopefully that helps. As we have broken every rainfall record in January it certainly didn't help

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, there's no way we could tell without soil testing; please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.